# get PThreads version compatible with PHP installed version

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I've a project in PHP 5.6 and I need to install PThreads, the thing is that I haven't found the correspondance of the compatiblity between version of PHP and Pthreads. I was looking for it but I cannot find it yet, [here I found all the releases](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/) but I don't know which is compatible with my PHP version, for other side, in my production server I have another version of PHP, so it would be very helpful a list of the PHP versions that matches with the available releases oh PThread. or, how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

First find out your 'PHP Extension Build' version via phpinfo(), i.e. http://localhost/?phpinfo=1

Download the pthreads that matches your php version and php extension build, I think it's VC11 right now. Then go grab the pthreads version from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/

If you're on Linux then you'll get the right version with:

wget http://pecl.php.net/get/pthreads-1.0.0.tgz

followed by apt-get update pthreads

Comment: yes, I read that but it doesn't make me clear to me. The PHP 5.6v is the 20131106 API, the I go that page but how I know which matches with my PHP, I tried to install the 2.0.05 version, but I get this: Unable to initialize module. Module compiled with module API=20121212 PHP Compiled with Module Api=20131226 These options need to match